# ofstream wont create files in documents folder

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I'm trying to make a function for a game I'm making that saves data from the game to a text file in a folder, both with a name provided by the user. I was able to do this in my project folder, and wanted it to be in a more universal place, so I am trying the documents folder.

When I switched the locations, however, the code stopped producing the desired result, and started creating the file and the folder in my program's main directory. (the file is not in the folder, fyi)

```
void Player::save()
{
system("mkdir \"C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\""); 
   //Make "Ice Road" folder in documents
std::string filename((name + ".txt")); 
   //make a name (inputed by the user earlier) to later be used to name a text file

std::string command("mkdir "); 
   //string to be combined with name to make folder
std::string commandString((command + name)); 
   //combine to make string command that creates folder
std::string newDir = ("C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\\" + name); 
   //string to set directory to newly created folder

std::ofstream saveStream;
   //open output stream for the saving process
SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\\");
   //set the directory to the Ice Road documents folder (DOES NOT WORK)
system((commandString.c_str()));
   //create named folder for the save files.

SetCurrentDirectory(newDir.c_str());
   //set the directory to the newly created folder
saveStream.open(filename.c_str());
   //Create/open a text file that holds the data being saved
system("echo on");
   //turn on echo for debugging

saveStream << name << std::endl 
<< difficulty << std::endl 
<< health << std::endl 
<< warmth << std::endl 
<< hunger << std::endl 
<< packSpace << std::endl 
<< packUsed << std::endl;
saveStream.close();
   //input data to save file

system("dir");
   //show folder for debugging  
system("PAUSE");
   //wait for input
}
```

How could I get this code to create a folder in documents called Ice Road, with the named folder inside and the named text file inside that?

(Documents\Ice Road\yourname\yourname.txt)

Comment: I would try using `"C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\\" + name + ".txt"` as `filename`.

Comment: @Dietmar: that's #2 on my list, #1 is putting that directory name into a variable and reusing it, to make sure all paths actually are the same name.

Comment: @MaximumTurtles: You are saying the file opened with the `filename` as in my previous comment is created in a different directory than `"C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\\"`? You should print the content of `filename` right before you open the stream!

Comment: @DietmarKühl the filename was "C:\Users\Default\Documents\Ice Road\name.txt", which was wrong, but when I corrected it to "C:\Users\Default\Documents\Ice Road\name\name.txt" there was no change.

Comment: Why are you using `system` to create a directory when http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx would be a lot better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. My biggest problem was that I had no access to this folder (UAC), but because I wasn't receiving any errors I didn't think of it. Between that and some other tweaking I got it to work as shown below, running as administrator.

```
void Player::save()
{
std::string iceroad("C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road");
    //Ice road directory, made into a string variable for easy usage, as recommended by Ben
system("mkdir \"C:\\Users\\Default\\Documents\\Ice Road\""); 
    //Make Ice Road folder in documents
std::string filename(iceroad + "\\" + name + "\\" + name + ".txt"); 
    //make a name (inputed by the user earlier) to later be used to name a text file, now using full address

std::string command("mkdir "); 
    //string to be combined with name to make folder
std::string commandString((command + name)); 
    //combine to make string command that creates folder
std::string newDir = (iceroad + "\\" + name); 
    //string to set directory to newly created folder, simplified

std::cout << filename;
    //debugging, as reccommended by Dietmar
std::ofstream saveStream;
    //open output stream for the saving process
SetCurrentDirectory(iceroad.c_str());
    //set the directory to the Ice Road documents folder
system("dir");
    //debugging, as recommended by Dietmar
system((commandString.c_str()));
    //create named folder for the save files.

SetCurrentDirectory(newDir.c_str());
    //set the directory to the newly created folder
saveStream.open(filename.c_str());
    //Create/open a text file that holds the data being saved
system("echo on");
    //turn on echo for debugging

saveStream << name << std::endl 
<< difficulty << std::endl 
<< health << std::endl 
<< warmth << std::endl 
<< hunger << std::endl 
<< packSpace << std::endl 
<< packUsed << std::endl;
saveStream.close();
    //inputs data to save file

system("dir");
    //show folder for debugging 
system("PAUSE");
    //wait for input
 }
```

Thank you for your constructive critiques, I did take them to heart and implement them.